# Python: How to move forward or backward together in String printable

Tags: python

How to shift forward or backward in `string.printable` whithout `string.maketrans`?

for example:

```
>> chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

and then output is:

```
123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0
```

Comment: Move the first char in a string to the last, and vise versa?

Comment: there are two conditions: `one` character and `two` characters or `more`.. can help me please?

Comment: chars[1:]+chars[0] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> chars[2:] + chars[:2]
'23456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> chars[-2:] + chars[:-2]
'YZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX'
>>>
```

You can even define a function for that, with your string, the steps and direction as parameters:

```
>>> def shift(s, step, side='Right'):
        step %= len(s) #Will generate correct steps even step > len(s)
        if side == 'Right':
            return s[-step:]+s[:-step]
        elif side == 'Left':
            return s[step:]+s[:step]
        else:
            print 'Please, Specify either Right or Left shift'
            return -1 #as exit code


>>> shift(chars, 2, 'Right')
'YZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX'
>>> shift(chars, 2, 'Left')
'23456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01'
>>> f(chars, 2, 'No_Direction')
Please, Specify either Right or Left shift
-1
```

Another way is to use [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.deque) class of the `collections` module, which has `rotate` method, this way:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> 
>>> d = deque(chars)
>>> d
deque(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'])
>>> 
>>> d.rotate(1)
>>> d
deque(['Z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y'])
>>> d.rotate(-1)
>>> d
deque(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'])
>>> d.rotate(3)
>>> ''.join(list(d))
'XYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW'
```

Comment: thanks so much sir.. that was i need..

Comment: Note that if `len(s) > step` the result will always be `s`. If the op wants to shift by more than `len(s)`, you should first perform `step %= len(s)` to compensate.

Comment: @Mirac7 .. Thanks for the Head's up

Answer (score 0):

You can get that by slicing after the last character index you'd like to shift, `1` in this case:

```
result = chars[1:] + chars[:1]
```